# Docker + PHP - ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I'm following this [guide](http://tech.osteel.me/posts/2015/12/18/from-vagrant-to-docker-how-to-use-docker-for-local-web-development.html) to set up a PHP development environment with Docker.

I have created a folder **on my desktop** `docker-php` and added a `docker-compose.yml` file into it, with this content:

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - 80:80
```

On my terminal:

```
$ cd /home/my-username/Desktop/docker-php/
$ docker-compose up -d
```

I get this error:

> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at
>   http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?
>
> If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the
>   DOCKER_HOST environment variable.

I'm on Xubuntu 16.04.

Or perhaps I should put the folder in the specific location that is required by Docker? If so, which is it?

Comment: adduser YOURUSER docker

Comment: @opHASnoNAME sorry i don't get it.

Comment: Add your user to the docker group or try to run the container as root. You cannot access the socket as "normal" user on linux.

Comment: @opHASnoNAME `Add your user to the docker group` - how do i do that?

Comment: sudo adduser USER docker :-)

Comment: @opHASnoNAME Or perhaps I should put the folder in the specific location that is required by Docker? If so, which is it?

Comment: Eh? Just try to add your linux user into the "docker" group with adduser.

Comment: done that. but now with the new error `ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.
`

Comment: Hmm sorry no idea about your setup. Docker-Machine is not used on linux os as far as i know

Comment: it is painful to work on docker!

Comment: @DanLowe i follow the steps to install Docker before installing `docker-machine`. I have the error above and I googled around and all it points me to  `docker-machine`! Now I have to uninstall everything - including Docker! What a hype building around such a unfriendly technology!

Comment: @DanLowe i'm lost! why do i get the error in my question above then?

Comment: I did follow the steps from https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/ exactly and then I have this error when I try to set up the env for php following this http://tech.osteel.me/posts/2015/12/18/from-vagrant-to-docker-how-to-use-docker-for-local-web-development.html

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason for this error is that you ran 'docker-compose up' without sudo. As long as there is docker installed and is up and running, you are likely missing sudo in the docker command.

Answer (score 1):

### You could use native Docker

One option is to abandon docker-machine and use a native Docker setup on your system. Since you are on Linux (Xubuntu), this is an option for you. docker-machine is most often used by people who can't run Docker natively (Mac or Windows), and use it to install a Docker-capable VM and some local commands on their OS to talk to it.

You can find install docs for Docker on Linux [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/).

However, you already have docker-machine installed, so this may be the most disruptive option for you.

### Your docker-machine may not be running

The error you are getting is saying the Docker client cannot talk to the server. One potential reason for this is that your docker-machine VM isn't running. You should verify it is running, and if not, start it.

To get a list of your docker-machines (may be one or more):

```
docker-machine ls
```

You will probably have one machine named `default`, but you may have more, depending on how you did your setup.

You can get the current status with:

```
docker-machine status <machine-name>
```

And you can use `stop`, `start`, `restart` to manage the docker-machine.

(More in the [Docker Machine CLI reference](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/).)

### You need the proper environment set

docker-machine relies on environment variables to work properly. Because you may have multiple docker-machine setups, you have to tell the client which one to use.

To set the environment, you can get it from the docker-machine command.

```
docker-machine env <machine-name>
```

And you can automatically inject it into the environment (this may be a useful thing to put into your shell startup file).

```
eval "$(docker-machine env <machine-name>)"
```

You should end up with env vars similar to these:

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.101:2376
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/nathanleclaire/.docker/machines/.client
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=dev
```

Keep in mind you should use the eval form here, not just run the `env` command and paste the output into your shell setup; it may change on a docker-machine restart, etc, so you can't rely on an old setup to still work later.

If your docker-machine is running, and these env vars are set, your docker and docker-compose commands *should* work.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I prefer not to use `docker-machine`. I prefer using `native Docker`. I dont' want to install virtualbox becos it makes things complicated. how can I remove `docker-machine`?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker USERNAME
```

Comment: Did that solve it for docker-machine, or was that after going to native Docker?